# Parameterizing JDBC call in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Parameterizing the SQL query in Jmeter

I am trying to load test a select statement and need to parameterize the filter condition. I am parameterizing the input filed by ${input}. Getting an error message ORA-00911: invalid character

sample:

```
input_sys AS
 (SELECT DISTINCT sys_id AS xxxxx --
    FROM table_t
   WHERE xxx_id IN (${input})),...…
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using csv data set config I tried  with ${__CSVRead(data.csv,0)} and that solves the issue.